# AWS CodeBuild artifact handling

Tags: aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

So I have a react with SSR project that I am trying to create a CI/CD pipeline. My project needs to deploy the following artifacts:

- dist folder created by Webpack
- appspec.yml file needed by Code Deploy
- script folder for scripts that are references in appspec.yml

When I tried to get the files one by one using this buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
 install:
   runtime-versions:
     nodejs: 10
   commands:
     - npm install
 build:
   commands:
     - npm run build
artifacts:
  files:
    - 'dist/*'
    - 'appspec.yml'
    - 'deploy-scripts'
```

I got dist with only part of it's content and the appspec.yml and the deploy scripts folder.

Then I tried a different approach:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10
    commands:
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - npm run build
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: "dist"
  discard-paths: yes
```

The dist folder has the scripts and the appspec file inside it. Now it does deploy, but I lose the folder structure of dist which is necessary for my deploy scripts.

I need to get all the contents of dist in their folder structure. As well as the scripts and the appspec.yml file. The scripts and the appspec.yml can't be inside dist, but dist needs to have all of it's content.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Looks like you got the answer from AWS forums already, which was to make it 'dist/**/*' in your first buildspec. Reference: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=307600

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to use the first buildspec file and adding "**/*" to the dist directory.

So in the dist line it ends up being this: "dist/**/*".

So if we apply this to the general context, anytime you want to get a directory to be sent along with single files in the build phase, you can add it like this:

"[directory_name]/**/*"

And that will get you both the directory and everything inside it in a recursive way.

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding your working `buildspec.yml` instead of explaining it.

Comment: Most definitely agree, but I don't work on that project anymore and we ended up changing the infrastructure of it, so I can't do that anymore.